# Global lists are updating in thread but not showing in simple functions

Tags: python, multithreading, scope, global-variables

```
# importing package
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
from nltk.translate import bleu
from nltk import cluster
import pandas as pd
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
from Levenshtein import ratio

global generatedSumamrycosineScore
global generatedSumamryjaccordScore
global originalSummaryLevenshteinScore
global originalSummaryScore
global sum_model
generatedSumamrycosineScore = []
generatedSumamryjaccordScore = []
originalSummaryLevenshteinScore = []
originalSummaryScore = []
sum_model = pipeline('summarization', model='facebook/bart-large-cnn')


def findCosine_Similarity(article, summary):
    counter1 = Counter(article.split())
    counter2 = Counter(summary.split())
    all_items = set(counter1.keys()).union(set(counter2.keys()))
    sim = []
    v1 = [counter1[k] for k in all_items]
    for b in summary.split('. '):
        if b.strip() != '':
            c2 = Counter(b.split())
            v2 = [c2[k] for k in all_items]
        sim.append({'article_line': article, 'summary_line': b,
                    "similarity": cluster.util.cosine_distance(v1, v2)})
    df = pd.DataFrame(sim)
    df_sum = df[abs(df['similarity']) >= 0.75]
    s = '. '.join(df_sum['summary_line'].to_list())

    return bleu([s.split()], article.split())


def jaccard_similarity(art, summary):
    s1 = set(art.split(' '))
    sum = []
    for b in summary.split('. '):
        if b.strip() != '':
            s2 = set(b.split(' '))
        sum.append({'article_line': art, 'summary_line': b, "similarity": float(
            len(s1.intersection(s2)) / len(s1.union(s2)))})
    df = pd.DataFrame(sum)
    df_sum = df[abs(df['similarity']) <= 0.25]
    s = '. '.join(df_sum['summary_line'].to_list())
    return bleu([s.split()], art.split())


def Levenshtein_similarity(art, summary):
    sum = []
    for b in summary.split('. '):
        if b.strip() != '':
            sum.append({'article_line': art, 'summary_line': b,
                        "similarity": ratio(art, b)})
    df = pd.DataFrame(sum)
    df_sum = df[abs(df['similarity']) >= 0.75]
    s = '. '.join(df_sum['summary_line'].to_list())
    return bleu([s.split()], art.split())


def PredictSummary(*art):
    try:
        global generatedSumamrycosineScore
        global generatedSumamryjaccordScore
        global originalSummaryLevenshteinScore
        global originalSummaryScore
        global sum_model
        l1 = art[0]
        summary = sum_model(l1)
        l2 = summary[0]['summary_text']
        generatedSumamrycosineScore.append(findCosine_Similarity(l1, l2))
        generatedSumamryjaccordScore.append(jaccard_similarity(l1, l2))
        originalSummaryLevenshteinScore.append(Levenshtein_similarity(l1, l2))
        originalSummaryScore.append(
            bleu([art[1].split()], l1.split()))

    except:
        pass


def run_process(*art):
    threadlist = []
    print("creating Threads")
    threadlist.append(Thread(target=PredictSummary,
                             args=list(art[0].values())[:2]))
    threadlist.append(Thread(target=PredictSummary,
                             args=list(art[1].values())[:2]))
    for t in threadlist:
        t.start()
    for t in threadlist:
        t.join()
    print("Threads created")

    global generatedSumamrycosineScore
    global generatedSumamryjaccordScore
    global originalSummaryLevenshteinScore
    global originalSummaryScore
    # Printing values here 
    print(generatedSumamrycosineScore, generatedSumamryjaccordScore, originalSummaryLevenshteinScore,
          originalSummaryScore)




def plot_graph():
    global generatedSumamrycosineScore
    global generatedSumamryjaccordScore
    global originalSummaryLevenshteinScore
    global originalSummaryScore

    # list values are empty here
    print(generatedSumamrycosineScore, generatedSumamryjaccordScore, originalSummaryLevenshteinScore,
          originalSummaryScore)

    plt.plot(generatedSumamryjaccordScore,
             label="generatedSumamryjaccordScore")
    plt.plot(generatedSumamrycosineScore, label="generatedSumamrycosineScore")
    plt.plot(originalSummaryLevenshteinScore,
             label="originalSummaryLevenshteinScore")
    plt.plot(originalSummaryScore, label="originalSummaryScore")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig("Bleugraph.png", dpi=1000)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    datasets = load_dataset('cnn_dailymail', '3.0.0')

    i = 0
    while i < 1000:
        try:
            print("started", i)
            art = []
            for k in range(0, 30):
                art.append(datasets['test'][i+k])
            processlist = []
            processlist.append(Process(target=run_process, args=art[:10]))
            for t in processlist:
                t.start()

            for t in processlist:
                t.join()
            break
            i += 30
        except:
            continue
    plot_graph()
```

I am creating a process in which i have to create almost 10 threads but currently using 2 thread. In each thread values are calculated and append in eac list. when i print he values in the `run_process` function where threads are created it prints the values but when i print hem in `plot_graph` these are null. I have make them global but still this issue occurs.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using processes? Globals aren't shared between processes, so that is why plot_graph doesn't see the results. As it currently stands, you can just call run_process directly instead of creating a process list. If say why you what you're trying to achieve using processes, I may be able to suggest a different solution.

Comment: oh ok. let me ask 2 questions. 1. is there any way to make global variables shared among process? 2. how many maximum threads I can make?

Comment: 1. If you don't know how to share global variables then you shouldn't share global variables, you'll only invite bugs, instead consider using `multiprocessing.pool` which allows you to start functions and get their return, or pass in `multiprocessing.manager.list` and append to it. 2. Enough threads to run out of RAM and crash your PC.